# Find number of element in the array using the pointer to the array in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, struct

please help me to implement function in C that take the pointer of array and return the number of elements in that array. I have an array of type My_Type like this:

```
typedef struct My_Type My_Type ;

struct My_Type {
    char *array[100];  //100 is the maximum length the array could have
}

My_Type *my_array = malloc(sizeof(My_Type));
```

After creating a heap memory for my_array, the array was added n number of element (n<=100). The function I'm trying to write look like this:

```
int Count(My_Type *array)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: This depends on how is data added to `array`. [Edit] the question to show that code (a [mre]).

Comment: You need to initialize all the unused elements of `array` to `NULL`. Then you can count the elements that aren't null.

Comment: @Barmar what if NULL is a valid value?

Comment: @0___________ Then you have a problem. But normally null pointers are used to indicate that an array element is not being used.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in C. C arrays do not have any metadata about their length or type. The only way is to store the size in the array or use more complex data type.

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    int arr[];
}int_arr_t;


int_arr_t *allocate(int_arr_t *array, size_t newsize)
{
    int_arr_t *arr = realloc(array, sizeof(*arr) + newsize * sizeof(arr -> arr[0]));

    if(arr)
    {
        arr -> size = newsize;
    }
    return arr;
}

size_t getCount(int_arr_t *arr)
{
    return arr ? arr -> size : 0;
}
```

Some remarks:
`malloc(sizeof(My_Type));` do not use types in the `sizeof` only objects.  If you change the type of the object you will not have to change other code. For example to follow type form your question only `typedef` has to be changed:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    char *arr[];
}int_arr_t;
```

The rest of the code will calculate the correct sizes without any changes. It is much safer and less prone to errors.